# Android: Insert immage button dynamically through code

Tags: java, android, image, button, imagebutton

i want to insert an image to do a button. But i want insert it through the code, no with the .xml file. There is someone that have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
ImageButton ib = new ImageButton(this);
yourContainer.addView(ib);//here yourContainer is ParentLayout
```

Comment: Your "container" will be a layout,for example LinearLayout, which in turn inherits this method from ViewGroup. Look for the documentation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View%29

Comment: how can i add an image to the image button?